# Переход на обратную строку

Tags: c++

Всем привет, суть задачи заключается в том, что нужно записать в текстовый файл какие-либо слова, и преобразовать эти слова в столбцы слов.
Как выходит у меня.
[image: Неправильно]

Как должно выглядеть.

[image: Правильно]

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


int main() 
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    ifstream fi;

    fi.open("da.txt");

    if (!fi.is_open())
    {
        cout << "ERROR" << endl;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Файл открылся" << endl;

        char sym;
        while (fi.get(sym))
        {   
            cout << sym << endl;
            if (sym == 32)
            {
                cout << endl;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Мой код:

Comment: запиши все слова в массив стрингов из файла, потом в цикле выводи по одной букве из каждого слова, первые буквы слов заканчиваются переводи на новую строку и выводи вторую букву из каждого и т.д.

Comment: проще всего записать слова в двумерный массив символов(первый столбец, первое слово, второй, второе и т.д. Чтобы сделать это, нужно найти самое длинное слово ,  чтобы количество строк был столько же. И для количества столбцов найти количество слов.  Оба значения можно вычислить прямо во время ввода. Неинициализированные элементы массива инициализировать пробелом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для такой печати проще всего прочесть все слова файла в память, запоминая их в векторе строк, поскольку такие контейнеры уже содержат функции (методы) для получения их размера.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

#include <stdio.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  ifstream in(av[1] ? av[1] : "/dev/tty");
  if (!in.good())
    exit((perror("input file"), 1));

  vector<string> v{};
  string s;

  // прочтем все слова файла в память
  while (in >> s) 
    v.push_back(s);

  // теперь выводим их буквы в несколько строк
  // в первую строку выводим первые буквы всех слов,
  // во вторую строку, вторые и т.д.
  // если в каком-то слове нет очередной буквы, то выведем пробел
  // в последней строке будут выведены последние буквы самых длинных слов

  int n = 1; // счетчик букв, выведенных в каждой строке, он же индикатор окончания работы
  for (int j = 0; n; j++) {
    n = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
      cout << (j < v[i].size() ? ++n, v[i][j] : ' ') << "  ";
    cout << '\n';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для решения Вашей задачи, Вам надо просто посмотреть на нее под другим углом (на 90 градусов) сдампите строки в массив и сдампите их в файл.
см. решение

учтите что массив надо выравнять по максимальной длине слова

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <array>


int main() {
    std::array<std::string, 2> arr{"mom", "dad"};

    std::ofstream out;
    out.open("out_table");

    if (!out.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Error open file" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::size_t max_size{3}; // эту велечину найдете сами. в словах меньше этой длинны, допишите точками или пробелами до максимальной длинны

    for (std::size_t i{0}; i <= arr.size(); ++i) {
        for (std::size_t j{0}; j < max_size ; ++j) {
            out << arr[j][i];
        }
        out << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```